# Docker, Why is my elasticsearch losing data?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I suspect I have setup something wrong.

Idea was that I have a data directory in host machine which is mapped to a directory in the docker container. (For the master node)

```
 services:
  es-log-00:
   volumes:
    - /var/lib/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

However I am using docker volumn for non-master node

```
  es-log-01:
   volumes:
    - data-log1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

-volumes:
   data-log1:
```

Here's my full docker file..

```
version: '3'

services:
 es-log-00:
  build:
    context: ../
    dockerfile: ./compose/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
    args:
      - VERSION=${VERSION}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_NETWORK_HOST=${ELASTICSEARCH_NETWORK_HOST}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
      - MEM=${MEM}
      - ENV=${ENV}
  container_name: es-log-00
  network_mode: host
  environment:
      - node.name=node-master
      - discovery.seed_hosts=node1,node2
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=node-master,node1,node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - cluster.name=littlehome-log
      - network.publish_host=192.168.1.105
  volumes:
   - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
   - /var/lib/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
   - /var/lib/elasticsearch-backup:/var/lib/elasticsearch-backup
   - /var/nfs/elasticsearch:/var/nfs/elasticsearch
  ulimits:
    memlock:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1
    nofile:
      soft: 65536
      hard: 65536

 es-log-01:
  restart: always
  build:
    context: ../
    dockerfile: ./compose/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
    args:
      - VERSION=${VERSION}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_NETWORK_HOST=${ELASTICSEARCH_NETWORK_HOST}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_SEARCH}
      - MEM=${MEM1}
      - ENV=${ENV}
  container_name: es-log-01
  network_mode: host
  environment:
      - node.name=node1
      - discovery.seed_hosts=node-master,node2
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=node-master,node1,node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - cluster.name=littlehome-log
      - network.publish_host=192.168.1.100
  volumes:
   - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
   - data-log1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
   - /var/nfs/elasticsearch:/var/nfs/elasticsearch
  ulimits:
    memlock:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1
    nofile:
      soft: 65536
      hard: 65536

 es-log-02:
  restart: always
  build:
    context: ../
    dockerfile: ./compose/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
    args:
      - VERSION=${VERSION}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_NETWORK_HOST=${ELASTICSEARCH_NETWORK_HOST}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_SEARCH}
      - MEM=${MEM2}
      - ENV=${ENV}
  container_name: es-log-02
  network_mode: host
  environment:
      - node.name=node2
      - discovery.seed_hosts=node-master,node1
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=node-master,node1,node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - cluster.name=littlehome-log
      - network.publish_host=192.168.1.104
  volumes:
   - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
   - data-log2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
   - /var/nfs/elasticsearch:/var/nfs/elasticsearch
  ulimits:
    memlock:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1
    nofile:
      soft: 65536
      hard: 65536


volumes:
  data-log1:
  data-log2:
```

Should I not use data volumes, and just use host machine directory as I did for es-log-00 ?

Or is there something else I should inspect?

Comment: I do not think the above ELK stack running in a cluster mode, can you verify that its running cluster mode because you are using `network_mode: host` where service to service communication does not work because container does not allocate IP address.  try to run `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v&pretty"` If its running as a cluster it will return `3` otherwise `1` so that might be create data inconsistent

Comment: I see 3 data nodes , so it's working.. the ips are machines' internal ips. (which I can  ssh into)